# Definition of two dimensional Gaussian process

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, gaussian

If $X=(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a one-dimensional Gaussian real process I know that it means that
$$
(X_{t_1}, X_{t_2}, \ldots , X_{t_n})
$$
has $n$-dimensional Gaussian distribution for any $0 \leq t_i< t_{i+1}$ for $i=1,2,....,n-1$ and $n \geq 1$. What if $(X,Y)$ is a two-dimensional Gaussian process. Does it mean that
$$
(X_{t_1}, X_{t_2}, \ldots , X_{t_n}, Y_{t_1}, Y_{t_2}, \ldots , Y_{t_n})
$$
has $2n$-dimensional Gaussian distribution for any $0 \leq t_i< t_{i+1}$ for $i=1,2,....,n-1$ and $n \geq 1$?

**Note** An answer is given in the post
[Definition of a $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued Gaussian process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3313305/definition-of-a-mathbbrd-valued-gaussian-process?rq=1).

Comment: I think a two-dimensional Gaussian process is more commonly understood to be a process where the index set is two-dimensional. This is contrasted with your one-dimensional process indexed by $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I don't agree. Gaussian processes on higher dimensional index sets are rather referred to as Gaussian fields. An $n$-dimensional Gaussian process, clearly is a Gaussian process valued $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: Now in order to also provide a hint towards a possible answer. One way to characterise a multivariate Gaussian RV $X$ is by imposing that the inner product $a\cdot X$ shall be a (scalar) Gaussian for every $a\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Can you cook up an answer yourself now?

Comment: @Tobsn Thank you. I know that definition of multivariate Gaussian random variables. I think I found an answer to my question in a related post, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3313305/definition-of-a-mathbbrd-valued-gaussian-process?rq=1

Comment: It's not a good answer. I may repeat myself: try to cook up a reasonable definition using the same philosophy as used in the definition of a multivariate Gaussian RV.

Comment: @Tobsn May I ask, in what sense do you think it is not a good answer?

Comment: It's not instructive, mainly because the definition in the question is already unfortunate.